# by jQuery adding a JSP page to another jsp page dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am using spring mvc I have make a popup by jquery and css and Popup will load data from server
and working well. But the problem is I want to laod popup dynamically using button click,
while page1.jsp is loading error message is:
     ......page2.jsp &quote not found........... please help.

page2.jsp

```
    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="overlay">
         .........

        <form:form id="testForm" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td> ok </td>
            </tr>
        </form:form>
         ..........
        </div>         
     </div>


     page1.jsp

     $("#btnClick").click(function(){
          $("#popupblock").load("../view/page2.jsp");
          custDialog(dialog);
     )};


      <html>
      ......
      <div>
          <input type="button" id="btnClick">
      </div>
      <div id="#popupblock">

      </div>
      .......
      </html>

     after button click should be appeared like that.
     <div id="popupblock">
       <jsp:include page="page2.jsp" />
    </div>

     If I assign statically then popup is loading data but 
     dynamically by jquery not working.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
$("#popupblock").load("../view/page2.jsp");
```

I think the path to the file is wrong, is it in the same directory? If so, just use `page2.jsp`. The file simply isn't found by the path you gave to it, so change it to the right path :)

Comment: if path is ok then $("#popupblock").load("../view/page2.jsp"); is the correct approach? are there any alternatives?